# nodejs doesn't connect to rethinkdb with docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, rethinkdb

How run rethinkdb with nodejs on server ?

Is docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  build: ./app
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    - "8080:8080"
    - "28015:28015"
    - "29015:29015"
  links:
    - "db:redis"
    - "rethink:rethinkdb"
  command: nodemon -L app/bin/www

db:
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379"
rethink:
  image: rethinkdb
```

is a folder app with nodejs-project and Dockerfile

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:0.10.38

RUN mkdir /src

RUN npm install nodemon -g

WORKDIR /src/app
ADD package.json package.json
RUN npm install

ADD nodemon.json nodemon.json
```

In the nodejs-project connection to rethinkdb:

```
module.exports.setup = function() {
  r.connect({host: dbConfig.host /* 127.0.0.1*/, port: dbConfig.port /*is 28015 or 29015 or 32783*/ }, function (err, connection) {
    ...
  });
};
```

And when run a `docker-compose up`, **have an error**

> Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:32783.

[image]

Comment: Sidenote: Don't use node v0.10. That version has no support anymore. Rather go to the current [LTS version](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS), v6 as of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

Try exposing the port in you `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
  build: ./app
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
    - db
    - rethink
  command: nodemon -L app/bin/www

db:
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"

rethink:
  image: rethinkdb
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    - "28015:28015"
    - "29015:29015"
```

Then `dbConfig.host = rethinkdb` and `dbConfig.port = 28015`:

```
module.exports.setup = function() {
      r.connect({host: dbConfig.host /* 127.0.0.1*/, port: dbConfig.port /*is 28015 or 29015 or 32783*/ }, function (err, connection) {
        ...
      });
};
```

Hope you find this helpful.